# Codeigniter: how to display each employee's details once logged in their each account?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm currently working on codeigniter. I wanna display the logged in of each employee's details from mysql database to a view page. Where the employee logs in and it directs to employee's page.

I'm hoping someone can help me with my problem. Basically I have done creating a login system, whereas employees can log in to view their details (Employee ID, Name, Designation, Time-in, Time-out, Duration). But I'm confused on how I can display an employees results based upon who has logged in.

For example if I login the username "JasonGriffin", the result will be like this [JasonGriffin's details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIiD4.png)

There are 2 tables of mysql database, one called **employees** and one called **times** & here is their relation of this image [employees and times relation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1ocn.png)

Here is the controller (home.php)

```
public function goClock($message = null) {
        $this->load->view('imports/header');
        $this->load->view('imports/menu');

        if (!is_null($this->input->post('login'))) {
            $username = $this->input->post('user');
            $password = $this->input->post('password');

            $userdata = $this->model_home->get_userinfo($username, $password);
            //$userdata += array('is_loggedin' => true);
            //array_merge(array('is_loggedin' => true));

            $_SESSION['is_loggedin'] = true;  

            if ($userdata !== false) {
                $this->session->set_userdata($userdata);
                if($userdata['user_type'] == 1){
                    redirect('home/goHome');
                } else if ($userdata['user_type'] == 0){
                    redirect('home/goEmployee');
                }
            }else {
                $data['login_error'] = '<p style="font-size: 16px; color: red;" align="center">Invalid Username or Password</p>';
                $this->load->view('login', $data);
            }
        }else {
            $data['username'] = $this->input->post('user');
            $data['password'] = $this->input->post('password');
            $this->load->view('clock', $data);
        }
    }

public function goEmployee() { 
        $this->load->model('Model_attendance');
        $query = $this->Model_attendance->getEmployees();
        $data['EMPLOYEES'] = null;
        if ($query) {
            $data['EMPLOYEES'] = $query;
        }
        $this->load->view('imports/header');
        $this->load->view('imports/menu');
        $this->load->view('employee', $data);
    }
```

Here is the model (model_attendance.php)

```
public function getEmployees() {
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from('employees');
        $this->db->join('times', 'times.userID = employees.empnum');
        $this->db->join('designation', 'designation.designation_id = employees.designation_id');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Here is the model (model_home.php)

```
public function get_userinfo($username = null, $password = null) {
        if ($username && $password) {
            $this->db->select('username, password, empnum, user_type, lastname');
            $this->db->where('username', $username);
            $this->db->where('password', $password);
            $query = $this->db->get('employees');
            if ($query->num_rows()) {
                return $query->result_array()[0];
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Here is the view (employee.php)

```
<table class="table table-striped responsive-utilities jambo_table" id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr class="headings">
            <th>Employee ID</th>      
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Designation</th>
            <th>Time-in</th>
            <th>Time-out</i></th> 
            <th>Duration</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($EMPLOYEES as $employee){

            $timein = $employee->timein;
            $timein = explode(' ', $timein);
            $date = nice_date($timein[0], 'F d Y');
            $hour = $timein[1];
            $regular_time_str = date( 'g:i A', strtotime( $hour ) );
            $timein = $date . "&nbsp&nbsp" . $regular_time_str;

            if(!is_null($employee->timeout)){

                $timeout = $employee->timeout;
                $timeout = explode(' ', $timeout);
                $date = nice_date($timeout[0], 'F d Y');
                $hour = $timeout[1];
                $regular_time_str = date( 'g:i A', strtotime( $hour ) );
                $timeout = $date . "&nbsp&nbsp" . $regular_time_str;
            }else { 

                $timeout = ' '; 
            }
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td data-order="<?php echo $employee->timein; ?>"><?php echo $employee->userID; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $employee->name; ?> <?php echo $employee->lastname; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $employee->position; ?></td>
                <td data-order="<?php echo strtotime($employee->timein);?>"><?php echo $timein; ?></td>
                <td data-order="<?php echo strtotime($employee->timeout);?>"><?php echo $timeout; ?></td>
                <td><?php 
                if($employee->hasClockOut==1){
                    $date1=new DateTime($employee->timein);
                    $date2=new DateTime($employee->timeout);
                    $employee->hours= $date1->diff($date2);
                    echo $employee->hours->format('%h')."H ".$employee->hours->format('%i')."M";
                } else { echo " "; }
                ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public function getEmployees() { 
    $this->db->where("employees.userID","$_SESSION['empnum']"); 
    $this->db->join('times', 'employees.userID =times.empnum' as enm); 
    $this->db->join('designation', 'employees.designation_id =       designation.designation_id' as desig); $query = $this->db->get(); 
return $query->result(); 
}
    Now Try this function.
```

Comment: public function getEmployees() {
        $this->db->where("employees.userID","$_SESSION['empnum']");
        $this->db->join('times', 'employees.userID =times.empnum' as enm);
        $this->db->join('designation', 'employees.designation_id = designation.designation_id' as desig);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }      Now try this and put variable enm,desig respectively

Comment: You can edit your answer if you want. (Look for the edit button)

Comment: I got this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

Comment: @BhavinBhandari your answer has syntax errors. And you should try to have a short explanation of what you're code does/how it should be used. Also, I don't think that forcing the getEmployees function to always look at the session empnum is a good idea (what if you need a different employee?)